# What does Ruby 'to' function do?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

Pardon the very basic question, but I'm not a Ruby programmer and I need to understand a line of Ruby code:

```
redirect to('/')
```

redirect is from Sinatra and I understand what it does, but 'to' is such a common word that however I try to Google this function, I can't find it. Following modules are imported:

```
require 'cgi'
require 'sinatra'
require 'gollum'
require 'mustache/sinatra'
require 'useragent'
require 'stringex'
```

And in case it is needed, the [whole file](https://github.com/github/gollum/blob/master/lib/gollum/frontend/app.rb) or some [shorter one](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-ruby-client/wiki/OAuth2) that I managed to find.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method is [`Sinatra::Helpers#uri`](http://rubydoc.info/gems/sinatra/Sinatra/Helpers%3auri), and it is aliased (also available) as `url` and `to`. It creates an absolute url based on given arguments.

So, nothing but a readable method name provided by Sinatra.

Comment: I was looking at Sinatra API doc, but I failed to find it, because I was not aware of aliases. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's not a standard ruby function, it is probably a DSL function defined by a framework such as sinatra.  Look [here](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/1e0a6472717f6ee5054ddd1e67d1af41b4f80c91/lib/sinatra/base.rb#L199):

Answer (score 1):

You can find a lot of information at http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html

### Browser Redirect

You can trigger a browser redirect with the redirect helper method:

```
get '/foo' do
  redirect to('/bar')
end
```

Any additional parameters are handled like arguments passed to halt:

```
redirect to('/bar'), 303
redirect 'http://google.com', 'wrong place, buddy'
```

You can also easily redirect back to the page the user came from with redirect back:

```
get '/foo' do
  "<a href='/bar'>do something</a>"
end

get '/bar' do
  do_something
  redirect back
end
```

To pass arguments with a redirect, either add them to the query:

```
redirect to('/bar?sum=42')
```

Or use a session:

```
enable :sessions

get '/foo' do
  session[:secret] = 'foo'
  redirect to('/bar')
end

get '/bar' do
  session[:secret]
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The ruby method `alias` aliases `uri` to `to` and performs as advertised in the comment.

```
# lib/sinatra/base.rb
# Generates the absolute URI for a given path in the app.
# Takes Rack routers and reverse proxies into account.
def uri(addr = nil, absolute = true, add_script_name = true)
  return addr if addr =~ /\A[A-z][A-z0-9\+\.\-]*:/
  uri = [host = ""]
  if absolute
    host << "http#{'s' if request.secure?}://"
    if request.forwarded? or request.port != (request.secure? ? 443 : 80)
      host << request.host_with_port
    else
      host << request.host
    end
  end
  uri << request.script_name.to_s if add_script_name
  uri << (addr ? addr : request.path_info).to_s
  File.join uri
end

alias url uri
alias to uri
```